# How do I get audio duration for the FileField in Django?

Tags: python, django, audio

Consider having this model:

```
class MusicTrack(models.Model):
    """
    Represents a music track
    """

    title = models.CharField("Track title", max_length=300)
    audio_file = models.FileField("Audio file", upload_to='audio/%Y-%m-%d/')

    duration_seconds = models.PositiveIntegerField("Track duration ins seconds", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Music track \"{self.title}\""
```

How do I get the audio duration in seconds and save it in the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [mutagen](http://mutagen.readthedocs.io) for getting audio information like duration.

To save it you can connect a [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal to your django model and update the `duration_seconds` field. It's a good idea to do it only when the actual file was updated, to reduce disk i/o and improve performance.

The signal receiver code will be something like this:

```
# considering model has audio_field = FileField()       
import mutagen

def some_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, raw, using, update_fields, **kwargs):

    file_was_updated = False
    if hasattr(instance.audio_file, 'file') and isinstance(instance.audio_file.file, UploadedFile):
        file_was_updated = True

    if update_fields and "audio_file" in update_fields:
        file_was_updated = True          

    if file_was_updated:
        # read audio file metadata
        audio_info = mutagen.File(instance.audio_file).info
        # set audio duration in seconds, so we can access it in database
        instance.duration_seconds = int(audio_info.length)

        print(">> audio duration was was updated")

    else:
        print(">> file not changed - duration was NOT updated")
```